# Worked on finding errors on server : Is my sentence correct

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

My manager asked me what have you done last 15 days. Please send me document.

In that document I have written one point

> Worked on finding errors on server.

I am not sure this sentence is correct grammatically. I am confuse at `Worked` and `Finding`.
Could you please help me?

Comment: Please somebody help me :(

Comment: It sounds normal.  From a grammar purist point of view it might be missing a word or two, like "I worked on finding errors on the server", but in a business English, bullet-point context it sounds fine as it is.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu - Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, saying *I worked on finding something* is quite common. For instance, if you look into **[Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)**, you could find:

> ...from 1998 to 2000 Ivins **worked on finding vaccines** for anthrax...

Then, saying *on the server* is also idiomatic. For instance, usage of *to find something on the server* can be found in the **Corpus** too:

> What happens is they **find the emails on the server.**

So, your final sentence may look as follows:

> I've been working on finding errors on the server for the last 2 weeks.